# Scroll text inside recyclerview element

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a recyerview which contains in each row a picture, a title and a description.[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fuyrq.png).

The height of an element of the recyclerview is fixed.

The problem is the description could be too long for the fixed height.
To solve it I would like to implement a vertical scrolling that could allow me to read everything in any cases.

I have no idea where I have to search to do that.
Someone has a good tutorial to follow ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you will get scroll conflicts by doing this as the recyclerview will not know whether to scroll itself upwards or to scroll the actual text inside it's views.

A better approach is to implement an expandable textview, an easy to use library can be found here:

https://github.com/Manabu-GT/ExpandableTextView